# How do I make a regular expression that matches everything on a line after a given character?

Tags: javascript, regex

If I have a String in JavaScript

```
key=value
```

How do I make a RegEx that matches `key` excluding `=`?

In other words:

```
var regex = //Regular Expression goes here
regex.exec("key=value")[0]//Should be "key"
```

How do I make a RegEx that matches `value` excluding `=`?

I am using this code to [define a language for the Prism syntax highlighter](http://prismjs.com/extending.html#language-definitions) so I do not control the JavaScript code doing the Regular Expression matching nor can I use `split`.

Comment: Do you want that to return the value that is in place of the key? Are you using grep/any other program or do you want to use it in a programming language? Which one?

Comment: I would just split it: ``'key=value'.split('=');``.

Comment: Not an option. I am writing an extension for prismjs to highlight syntax in Java properties files. It takes RegEx's.

Comment: What should it do for `foo=bar=baz`?

Comment: Ideally `foo` would be matched by the first regular expression and `bar=baz` by the second.

Comment: @acheong87 split is faster. Before Adam changed the question I started on a fiddle to prove it, and to test other methods. Maybe it still can be used to select the fastest regexp. http://jsfiddle.net/some/c2Kjs/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you could do this:

```
/^[^=]*/     // anything not containing = at the start of a line
/[^=]*$/     // anything not containing = at the end of a line
```

It might be better to look into Prism's `lookbehind` property, and use something like this:

```
{
    'pattern': /(=).*$/,
    'lookbehind': true
}
```

According to [the documentation](http://prismjs.com/extending.html) this would cause the `=` character not to be part of the token this pattern matches.

Answer (score 0):

```
.*=(.*)
```

This will match anything after =

```
(.*)=.*
```

This will match anything before =

Look into greedy vs ungreedy quantifiers if you expect more than one = character.

Edit: as OP has clarified they're using javascript:

```
var str = "key=value"; 
var n=str.match(/(.*)=/i)[1]; // before =
var n=str.match(/=(.*)/i)[1]; // after =
```

Comment: I would recommend `[^=]*=(.*)` - more efficient (though with really short keys and a non-compiled language, perhaps `.*`... _would_ be more efficient? hmmmmm

Comment: The `[1]` portion is not really available to me. Is there a Regex that would only match value and not `=value`

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I just edited the question to clarify what I need.

Comment: @CodeJockey I started on a jsfiddle before OP changed the question. You can test whats more efficient there: http://jsfiddle.net/some/c2Kjs/

Answer (score 0):

use this regex `(^.+?)=(.+?$)`

group 1 contain key

group 2 contain value

but split is better solution

Answer (score 0):

```
var regex = /^[^=]*/;
regex.exec("key=value");
```